# What is the correct approach to upgrade Database in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

If I want to keep some of the old data and migrate to a new version of database , what is the correct steps in onUpgrade method?

1. retain old data
2. drop old tables
3. create new tables and insert old data

Is there a simplified version or there is a better way? Thanks!

Comment: are you changing the schema of the tables in which you want to retain data?

Comment: You should be retaining the old data if that it user created. You can always alter tables to modify the table structures.

Comment: @sachingarg, yeah, the database schema is changed and part of the old data must be restored, cheers.

Comment: @WenChao , i don't think any simplified way is possible. One approach I can think is, alter all the tables in onUpgrade method and then insert the default values for newly added columns. (data for all the existing columns will be preserved.) . Just make sure you are not using any drop/delete statement in on-upgrade.

Comment: @sachingargYeah, seems like we have to write some boilerplate code eventually. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

upgrade database:

**add new fields in table**

do below steps in onUpgrade

1. copy old data in temp table
2. create new table with new fields
3. again copy data from temp to new table
4. drop temp table

also create new table in onCreate for new users

sample code for on upgrade

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            if (oldVersion < newVersion) {
                if (oldVersion == 3) {
                    /**
                     * code is upgrade privious version to letest version
                     * */
                    db.beginTransaction();
                    db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + TableConstants.TABLE_Mst.getTableName()
                + " RENAME TO " + TableConstants.TABLE_Mst.getTableName() + "_Obsolete");
        db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE_query_Mst);
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TableConstants.TABLE_Mst.getTableName() + "("
                + "f1, f2, f3) "
                + " SELECT f1, f2, f3 FROM " + TableConstants.TABLE_Mst.getTableName() + "_Obsolete");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "
                + TableConstants.TABLE_Mst.getTableName() + "_Obsolete");
                    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
                    db.endTransaction();
                    db.setVersion(newVersion);

                }
                }
                }
```

**add new table in database**

do below steps

in onUpgrade
1. create new table

in onCreate
1. create new table

Note: manage your database version, same for next version, check with older version its work or not.

Comment: It is wrong to use transactions or `setVersion` in `onUpgrade`; this is already handled by `SQLiteOpenHelper`.

Comment: In many cases, adding columns is possible with `ALTER TABLE ... ADD COLUMN ...` (see the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) for restrictions).